# Windows batch file to move files to subfolders based on file name

Tags: windows, batch

I had never built batches and I am having difficulty finding the syntax to do the following.
I have a ton of files stored in a single directory which I wish to move into subfolders(some already exist, others to be created) based on the following logic:

```
01202000088000.pdf

characters 1,2 -> first folder
characters 3,4 -> second folder
characters 5,6,7,8,9 -> third folder
```

I need to move `01202000088000.pdf` file to `01\2020\00088\`,
so renaming `01202000088000.pdf` to
`01\2020\00088\01202000088000.pdf`.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Edit:
Thanks to the advice I also created the batch version:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem For each file in your folder
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    echo filename=%%a
    rem check if the it is not our script
    if "%%a" NEQ "%0" (
        set foldername=%%a
        set foldername=..\!foldername:~0,2!\!foldername:~2,4!\!foldername:~6,5!\
        echo foldername=!foldername!
        rem check if forlder exists, if not it is created
        if not exist "!foldername!" mkdir "!foldername!"
        rem Move (or change to copy) the file to directory
        move "%%a" "!foldername!\"
    )
)
```

Comment: I looked at your user name, now I have a  song running through my head.......

Comment: Your example differs from your description. example shows `1-2\3-6\7-11\File.pdf`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TNT - You should remove the solution from your question and wait until the question is reopened before submitting a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're doing historical research, there's no reason to learn [batch](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77e51894-c591-469f-b3d3-982ab4f76ca7/if-else-if-condition-in-batch-files?forum=ITCG). Use **PowerShell**:

```
$Source = 'c:\PDF Folder'
GEt-ChildItem $Source *.pdf | ForEach{
   $Destination = ($_.Name.Substring(0,2)),($_.Name.Substring(2,4)),($_.Name.Substring(6,5)) -join '\'
   If ( -not ( Test-Path $Destination )) {
       mkdir $Destination | out-null
   }
   Move-Item $_.FullName $Destination
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method of doing it.
I myself like the batch function (via call) which is why I use it.  Others like using () parens and delayed expansion.  Neither are wrong.

As mentioned below, the function could have been squashed into two lines but then you wouldn't be able to understand what I was doing with string parsing so I left it verbose.

```bat
    @echo off

    :: This script assumes that all PDFs req'd are in the
    :: current directory and all have names with the format
    :: 01202000088000.pdf

    :: Get all of the PDF files in the current directory.  Pass them
    :: to a function called ParseFilenameMoveFile one at a time
    for %%f in (*.pdf) do call :ParseFilenameMoveFile "%%f"
    goto :EOF

    :: ----------------------------------------------------------------
    :: this could be folded into two lines but wouldn't be readable.
    :: ----------------------------------------------------------------
    :ParseFilenameMoveFile
    set InputFile=%~1
    set firstFolderChars=%InputFile:~0,2%
    set secondFolderChars=%InputFile:~2,4%
    set thirdFolderChars=%ParsedFilename:~6,5%

    set outputFolder=%firstFolderChars%\%secondFolderChars%\%thirdFolderChars%

    if not exist %outputFolder% mkdir %outputFolder%
    move %InputFile% %outputFolder%

    goto :EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

If the syntax is the same, try using a free renaming utility like Bulk Rename Utility.  From there sorting them into directories can probably be easily done in Windows Explorer.